# What type of antonym pair is borrow and lend? (and more generally, what's the relationship between relational vs. reversive antonyms?)

Tags: antonyms, semantics

I've seen different sources (linguistics textbooks, online sources) classify the pair as "reversive" or as "relational/converse" antonyms. More generally, it seems sources vary in their coverage of the main antonym types--they all discuss gradable and binary/complementary pairs, but some give reversives and not converse and vice versa. It makes me think they're often lumped together, but it seems reversives and converse antonyms are distinct. For example, it seems reversives are primarily verbs. Can reversives be seen as a sub-type of converse? Thanks for shedding any light on this!

Comment: From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(semantics)) *In linguistics, **converses** or **relational antonyms** are pairs of words that refer to a relationship from opposite points of view, such as parent/child or borrow/lend.* But I see nothing in the full OED to suggest ***reversive*** has any particular relevance to linguistics terminology. That connection only seems to exist in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reversive), which might not be a reliable source. Where are ***you*** getting the relevant definition from?

Comment: By "reversive", do you mean the _un-_ prefix in _unpack_ and _unravel_? It's not negative so much as it refers to reversing the actions. So much so that it can be added to a word like _ravel_ that already means _unravel_ to emphasize it.

Comment: As for _borrow_ and _lend_, they're simply split variants of _buy_ and _sell_, with the `HAVE` links augmented by `OWN` links that don't change with the transaction. Further details on [commercial transactions here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I came across "reversives" in George Yule's The Study of Language, 7th ed. (2020), p. 135; he writes, "Although we can use the 'negative test' to identify non-gradable antonyms in a language, we usually avoid describing one member of an antonymous pair as the negative of the other. For example, while _undress_ can be treated as the opposite of _dress_, it does not mean 'not dress.' It actually means 'do the reverse of dress.' Antonyms of this type are called **reversives**. Other examples are _enter/exit, pack/unpack, lengthen/shorten, raise/lower, tie/untie._"

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interestingly, the Wikipedia article on "oppposite (semantics)" does mention reversives but under ""classes of opposites" rather than categories of antonyms. Perhaps it's just a matter of different writers cutting the antonyms/opposites pie in different ways?!

Comment: @JohnLawler Given Yule's examples, it seems -un can appear in a reversive but it's not always the case. Thanks for the link to the article on commercial transactions; that's an interesting way to approach the analysis of money-related words.

Comment: Both "antonym" and "opposite" are vague terms indicating some kind of conventional opposition, but what that opposition is, or what dimension it lies in, varies quite a lot from one individual to another, and from one context to another. Not to mention from one language to another. So you're not gonna get precise terminology unless you address a particular context. Just look at the traditional Square of Opposition; three different ways of being "opposite", and it doesn't include reversives, or even specify verbs.